# Retrieve the contents of cookies using Java

Tags: java, cookies, selenium

I need to retrieve the properties of the cookies stored upon visiting a web page. Specifically,

1. Name
2. Host
3. Expiration Date

Is there a library that I can use?

EDIT: I apologize for the lack of detail..
I am employing Selenium to retrieve the WEB page. Asserting the presence of the cookie (and ultimately deleting it) is present in Selenium's native functionality. Reading the contents, however, is something I was hoping to do...

Comment: Is this a desktop Java app? How are you visiting the web page in question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are we talking about client-side Java (applets) or server-side?

Comment: @ Mike Baranczak, these would be the client-side cookies implanted on the user's browser

Comment: Are you driving Selenium from JUnit tests?

Comment: @Aravindan R, actually TestNG. But for all practical purposes, I am extending RC with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excellent resource I stumbled upon, using the java.net API - 
http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`selenium.getCookieByName("CookieName")`

to read the cookie by its name. This returns the cookie value as String

`selenium.getCookie()`

to get all the cookies in the page. You can assign this to a string and read it.

Finally to delete it you can use :

`selenium.deleteCookie("CookieName")`

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of Selenium's native cookie handling functions. Any idea on retrieving the host and the expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

For cookie handling use WebDrive manage()
e.g.
get cookie's value as string

```
driver.manage().getCookieNamed(cookieName).getValue();
```